# Prolog - Printing Result After Two Recursive Rules | Sum of Squares

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am brand new to prolog and I feel like there is a concept that I am failing to understand, which is preventing me from grasping the concept of recursion in prolog. I am trying to return `S`, which is the sum of the square of each digit, taken as a list from an integer that is entered by the user in a query. E.g The user enters `12345`, I must return `S = (1^2)+(2^2)+(3^2)+(4^2)+(5^2) = 55`.

In my program below, I understand why the each segment of the calculation of S is printed multiple time as it is part of the recursive rule. However, I do not understand how I would be able to print S as the final result. I figured that I could set a variable = to the result from sos in the second rule and add it as a parameter for intToList but can't seem to figure this one out. The compiler warns that S is a singleton variable in the intToList rule.

```
sos([],0).
sos([H|T],S) :- 
  sos(T, S1), 
  S is (S1 + (H * H)),
  write('S is: '),write(S),nl.

intToList(0,[]).
intToList(N,[H|T]) :- 
  N1 is floor(N/10), 
  H is N mod 10, 
  intToList(N1,T),
  sos([H|T],S).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```erlang
sos([],Accumulator,Accumulator).

sos([H|T],Accumulator,Result_out) :-
    Square is H * H,
    Accumulator1 is Accumulator + Square,
    sos(T,Accumulator1,Result_out).

int_to_list(N,R) :-
    atom_chars(N,Digit_Chars),
    int_to_list1(Digit_Chars,Digits),
    sos(Digits,0,R).

int_to_list1([],[]).

int_to_list1([Digit_Char|Digit_Chars],[Digit|Digits]) :-
    atom_number(Digit_Char,Digit),
    int_to_list1(Digit_Chars,Digits).
```

For `int_to_list` I used `atom_chars` which is built-in e.g.

```erlang
?- atom_chars(12345,R).
R = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].
```

And then used a typical loop to convert each character to a number using `atom_number` e.g.

```erlang
?- atom_number('2',R).
R = 2.
```

For `sos` I used an accumulator to accumulate the answer, and then once the list was empty moved the value in the accumulator to the result with

```erlang
sos([],Accumulator,Accumulator).
```

Notice that there are to different variables for the accumulator e.g.

```erlang
Accumulator1 is Accumulator + Square,
sos(T,Accumulator1,Result_out).
```

this is because in Prolog variables are immutable, so one can not keep assigning new values to the same variable.

Here are some example runs

```erlang
?- int_to_list(1234,R).
R = 30.

?- int_to_list(12345,R).
R = 55.

?- int_to_list(123456,R).
R = 91.
```

If you have any questions just ask in the comments under this answer.

Comment: You could optionally use `maplist` to convert your list of digit characters to a list of digits: `maplist(atom_number, Digit_Chars, Digits)`, which eliminates the need for `int_to_list1/2`. It's a nice standard predicate for per-element list processing/mapping.

Comment: Thank you very helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your original code is that you're trying to handle your call to `sos/2` within your recursive clause for `intToList/2`. Break it out (and rename `intToList/2` to something more meaningful):

```
sosDigits(Number, SoS) :-
    number_digits(Number, Digits),
    sos(Digits, SoS).
```

Here's your original `sos/2` without the `write`, which seems to work fine:

```
sos([], 0).
sos([H|T], S) :- 
  sos(T, S1), 
  S is (S1 + (H * H)).
```

Or better, use an accumulator for tail recursion:

```
sos(Numbers, SoS) :-
    sos(Numbers, 0, SoS).
sos([], SoS, SoS).
sos([X|Xs], A, SoS) :-
    A1 is A + X*X,
    sos(Xs, A1, SoS).
```

You can also implement `sos/2` using `maplist/3` and `sumlist/2`:

```
square(X, S) :- S is X * X.
sos(Numbers, SoS) :- maplist(square, Numbers, Squares), sumlist(Squares, SoS).
```

Your `intToList/2` needs to be refactored using an accumulator to maintain correct digit order and to get rid of the call to `sos/2`. Renamed as explained above:

```
number_digits(Number, Digits) :-
    number_digits(Number, [], Digits).

number_digits(Number, DigitsSoFar, [Number | DigitsSoFar]) :-
    Number < 10.
number_digits(Number, DigitsSoFar, Digits) :-
    Number >= 10,
    NumberPrefix is Number div 10,
    ThisDigit is Number mod 10,
    number_digits(NumberPrefix, [ThisDigit | DigitsSoFar], Digits).
```

The above `number_digits/2` also handles `0` correctly, so that `number_digits(0, Digits)` yields `Digit = [0]` rather than `Digits = []`.

You can rewrite the above implementation of `number_digits/3` using the `-> ;` construct:

```
number_digits(Number, DigitsSoFar, Digits) :-
    (   Number < 10
    ->  Digits = [Number | DigitsSoFar]
    ;   NumberPrefix is Number div 10,
        ThisDigit is Number mod 10,
        number_digits(NumberPrefix, [ThisDigit | DigitsSoFar], Digits)
    ).
```

Then it won't leave a choice point.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, it was very helpful.